# Find Azure Subscriptions Where I'm The Owner

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, subscription, azureportal, owner

I am trying to find which Azure Subscription has me as the Owner.

I have access to nearly 200 subscriptions within my company, one of which is supposed to have me as its Owner and the person who set this up is no longer available to assist with its identification. Is there a Powershell or any other CLI query I can run to iterate through the entire collection, to retrieve this critical piece of information for me?

Comment: You can login into the Portal and get this information. Simply search for or click on "Subscriptions". There you can will see the subscriptions you have access to and your role in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

login to your Azure portal and check the subscriptions blade:
[image]

Comment: https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions you can get metadata here but no roles or ownerships.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. However, I don't quite think that will give me the desired information. 

Why do I say that? Well, I'll give you an example. I have a private Azure Subscription where I'm the one and only user of that subscription. 

Even though I was the person who created that subscription, if I follow the steps you've outlined and filter on the "My role" dropdown for the Owner of the subscription, no result is displayed.

What would be ideal is to find perhaps the Subscription metadata that has an "Owner" attribute, with my name set as the value. Any ideas?

Comment: Let's see, can you see all your 200 subscriptions with your azure account user?? when you create a subscription you become an Account Admin, not an owner. You need to add this role, indeed every subscription should have at least 2 owners.

Comment: Yes, I can see all subscriptions with my Azure user account and you are correct, when one creates a subscription, you automatically become the Account Admin and not the Owner.

Answer (score 0):

Open the subscriptions blade, inside this blade you can filter subscriptions based on the Owner role.
[image: Subscription's role filter]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you had eliminated itself the owner assignment on the AccessControl(IAM).


You need to have **RBAC** access as *"Super Global User"* in your own AzureDirectory. And Re-Asign you as a suscription owner.


First go to *MicrosoftEntraID* in the AzurePortal and then go to **Manage->Properties** on the left side below the AzureBlade and click it, after this you see the name of your own directory, the TenantId and location, scroll down and you can see the configuration that says:


*"Access management for Azure resourcesContoso. (contoso@microsoft.com) can manage access to all Azure subscriptions and management groups in this tenant."* CLICK ON YES AND SAVE IT!! [SeeThis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaksQ.png)


Wait for 5 minutes to apply the *"SuperAdmin"* change, and go to your own suscription for this go to **"CostManagement"** in AzurePortal and then go to **Products+services->AzureSuscriptions** on the left side below the AzureBlade and click on it....can you see your own suscription rigth?? :D, click in it´s name.


Later go to **AccessControl(IAM)** on the left side below the AzureBlade and Yes! You finally can to add you as the subscription owner for this go to **Add+->AddRoleAssignement** and on the other blade click in **PrivilegedAdministratorRoles->Owner->Next->+SelectMembers->(You)->Next->Conditions->** *"Allow User to assign all roles (highly privileged)"*  **Next->Review+Asign->** 


Wait for 5 minutes to applying this and then let´s to un-assign the *"Super Global"* permissions (for security reasons) or the *"UserAccessAdministrator->RootInherited"* Role, Enter over again to *MicrosoftEntraID* in the AzurePortal and then go to  **Manage->Properties**  on the left side below the AzureBlade and click it, after this you see the name of your own directory, the TenantId and location, scroll down and you can see the configuration that says:


*"Access management for Azure resourcesContoso. (contoso@microsoft.com) can manage access to all Azure subscriptions and management groups in this tenant."* CLICK ON **NO** , AND SAVE IT!!.